# Why is webpack outputting the const keyword instead of var?

Tags: phantomjs, webpack, karma-webpack

Webpack appears to be outputting the const keyword instead of the var keyword which is breaking PhantomJS (as it doesn't support ES6 syntax).

```
...    

/* 2 */
/***/ function(module, exports, __webpack_require__) {    
    "use strict";
    const testing_1 = __webpack_require__(3); // const keyword breaking PhantomJS
    testing_1.describe('App', () => {
```

So PhantomJS reports

```
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Windows 8 0.0.0) ERROR
  SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'const'
```

The file in question (karma-shim.js) is being processed by the karma-webpack preprocessor

karma-shim.js

```
'use strict';

Error.stackTraceLimit = Infinity;
require('es6-shim');
require('angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js');
require('angular2/testing');

var appContext = require.context('./src', true, /root\.spec\.ts/);

appContext.keys().forEach(appContext);

var testing = require('angular2/testing');
var browser = require('angular2/platform/testing/browser');

testing.setBaseTestProviders(browser.TEST_BROWSER_PLATFORM_PROVIDERS, browser.TEST_BROWSER_APPLICATION_PROVIDERS);
```

karma.conf.js

```
...
preprocessors: {
    './karma-shim.js': ['webpack', 'sourcemap']
},
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "ES5",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "jsx": "react"
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules"
    ],
    "compileOnSave": false,
    "buildOnSave": false
}
```

webpack.config.js Is part of generator-ng2-webpack (https://github.com/cmelion/generator-ng2-webpack) but doesn't appear to mention transpilation.

Why would webpack be outputting const instead of var and is there anything I can do about it to help PhantomJS?

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Have you made any progress on this?

Comment: From memory, it turned out to be something quite obvious... somewhere along the line it was indeed transpiling to ES6, which it absolutely shouldn't.